# How to save/restore multiple tabs, each having multiple panels in iterm2?

Tags: iterm2

I routinely do maintenance on several clusters. Example:

```
Cluster A: IP1, IP2, IP3, IP4  
Cluster B: IP5, IP6  
Cluster C: IP7, IP8, IP9
```

And so on for several clusters

I am using iterm2 for doing this.
Problem is that every time I touch a cluster, I have to:

1. Lookup IPs in that cluster.
2. Split iterm2 into that many panes.
3. Enter each IP in a pane.
4. Select all panes and then enter my password.
5. Start doing something with the cluster.

The first 4 steps above are very error prone and very time consuming.

Is there a way that I can create profiles for each cluster and save the four steps above by a command like:

```
iterm2 -pane_file cluster1.txt
```